# Refactor Spring Async into RxJava way

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous, rx-java

I am New to RxJava, I have a project currently using Spring Async, trying to refactor it into RxJava way, don't know what would be elegant way.

We have a class UserService, which does the heavy job

```
@Async
public class UserService {
  public Future<User> fetchUsers(String space, String username) {
    // some other thing
    ...

    // call network APIs to fetch users for a space
    return new AsyncResult<>(clientOf.fetechUsers(space, username));
  }
}
```

Then in the caller:

```
List<Future<User>> users = new ArrayList<>();
String username = "alice";
for(String space : Arrays.asList("SPACE1", "SPACE2")) {
  users.add(userService.fetchUsers(space, username));
}

List<User> resultUsers = new ArrayList<>();
for(Future<User> user: users) {
  resultUsers.add(user.get());
}
return resultUsers;
```

In the caller, we want to call userService for two spaces in parallel, and then merge the result, how should I complete it with RxJava? I saw some example with Tread, do I have to manage Tread myself? or is there an elegant way to get the job done?

Answer (score 0):

Reading more I found out with RxJava 2 I realized that I can do things like:

```
Observable.just("SPACE1", "SPACE2")
          .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
          .map(space -> userService.fetchUsers(space, username))
          .blockingSubscribe(System.out::println);
```